# Benefits of applying field boosts at index time instead of query time in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, indexing

What is the benefit of applying a boost to a field at the time of indexing instead of doing it when constructing the search query and performing the search?

For instance, I could apply a boost to the "title" field when adding documents to the index, or just specify the boost when doing the search using a query like `(title:test)^10`.  Both seem like they would achieve the same thing, and I was wondering if there is any reason or benefit to do it one way as opposed to the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_field_.28or_document.29_boosting_and_query_boosting.3F) for the differences (from the Lucene FAQ, but applicable to Solr also)

> Index time field boosts are a way to express things like "this document's title is worth twice as much as the title of most documents". Query time boosts are a way to express "I care about matches on this clause of my query twice as much as I do about matches on other clauses of my query".
>
> Index time field boosts are worthless if you set them on every document.

Index-time boosts require [norms](http://www.lucidimagination.com/content/scaling-lucene-and-solr#d0e71) which will also enable field-length normalization. Depending on your use case, that may be a 'negative' or a 'don't care' for you.

Index-time boosts are slightly faster, but I think that the difference is negligible and query time boosts are almost always a better option due to the flexibility that they offer (no need to re-index if you want to change the weights).